# Would you rather make multiple async queries upfront and pass it on your child components, or split them?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

This is more of an open-ended question, but I was wondering what would be the preferred way of approaching this problem:

I have a `Tabs` component, and I was thinking of making multiple async calls in the parent Component, and then passing the necessary data on to the children like this:

```js
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    const res1 = useQuery(query1);
    const res2 = useQuery(query2);
    const res3 = useQuery(query3);
    const res4 = useQuery(query4);
    const res5 = useQuery(query5);

    if (
        res1.loading ||
        res2.loading ||
        res3.loading ||
        res4.loading ||
        res5.loading ||
    ) {
        return <LoadingCircle />
    }

    // Vaguely this, not exact
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tab>
                <ChildComponent1 data={res1.data} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <ChildComponent2 data={res1.data} otherData={res3.data}/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <ChildComponent3 data={res4.data} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <ChildComponent4 data={res2.data} otherData={res1.data} />
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

However I was thinking the initial load might be a bit big since it's getting a good amount of data... Would it be preferable to have each child component make its own async calls despite the possibility of it reusing the same query? For example:

```js
const ChildComponent1 = () => {
    const res1 = useQuery(getMember);
    const res2 = useQuery(getProgress);

    // ....
}

const ChildComponent2 = () => {
    const res1 = useQuery(getMember);
    const res2 = useQuery(getAppointment);

    // ....
}

const ChildComponent3 = () => {
    const res1 = useQuery(getOtherThing);
    // ....
}
```

That way the call would be less taxing initially, but would need to load each tab. I'm a bit confused on which method would be better/preferred.

I'm interested in how you all would approach this!

Comment: I would go with the second approach; I add a trick to all my tabs to avoid being unmounted when I change the current tab

Comment: I may explain further if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

### Separation of concern

if it is not required to do that, do that in respective component. Every component should get it's respective data through api and handle the way it should be. Components should be not be thick and only handle minimum required functionality insetad of putting every thing in one single giant component.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for an ecommerce website, in my case I prefer to load data (products) when the tab is clicked. So small fetches when changing the tab instead of a huge amount of data at once.

Just imagine how much would be first initial render if you have tons of items and all of them are coming at same time.

Big loading time would let the end user frustrated and most likely would make him leave the website.